# How can I force the use/on the name of a file in windows 11

Tags: windows

I wish I could use the special character especially /, I have to rename a file with / thank you for any help

- i use windows 11

Comment: **Why**? (I hope it's not because you want to put `dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy` dates in file-names, because they're not sortable: only `yyyy-MM-dd` is)

Comment: You can't. It's not legal in Windows filenames, and wishing won't change that at all. You'll have to pick another naming convention. It's impossible to tell you what to use, because you've provided no details about what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: No this for bypass file upload securit'y dont, I am soo lazy to use date ^^

Answer (score 0):

The slash and some other special characters are not allowed in filenames on Windows, so what you're asking for is not possible.

See [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) for details.

As other commenters have mentioned, to provide a workaround or alternative, you would need to provide more specifics about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I need to use / for file upload vulnérability for acces to the file with special attack for bypass security

Comment: Well, then I'm glad that this isn't possible ;-)

Answer (score 0):

We system admins prefer underscores for this very reason, unfortunately, windows isn't going to let you do that. File_Example.exe | underscores also helps readability in my opinion

Comment: opinion-based and not an answer actually